# How to write and then print a file in standard IO in Python?

Tags: python, file-handling

I am newbie to Python and started writing scripts which helps me in my daily routine work. Recently, I wrote a SSH script which will login to a server and check the connectivity with a remote Application and print if it is successful.

I am able to achieve it, but I could not see the complete print of the File(which I am writing to) on standard IO. Can anyone please have a look in my code and suggest a way how it should be done?

### My output from the code:-

```
*c:\Python27>python ssh1.py

['<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">\n', '</BODY></HTML>\n']

 HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">\n', '</BODY></HTML>\n']*
```

---

Not able to see the printout of "Site is up/down" although its written in the out.txt file.

```
ssh.connect('xx.xxx.xxx.xx', username= 'xxxxxx', password= 'xxxxx', port=22)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('wget -O- http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7777 | grep "HTML"') #some application IP
f = open('out.txt', 'w+',100)
sys.stdout=f
print stdout.readlines()
print f.read()
if 'HTML' in f.read():
    print "Site is up"
else:
    print "Site is down"
output = os.system ("type c:\python27\out.txt")
print output
f.close()
```

Comment: What do you mean - *I could not see the complete print of the File(which I am writing to) on standard IO* ?

Comment: @AnandSKumar- In my code, I am trying to do read the WGET response and then take a decision with IF/ELSE condition to write if "Site is up" or "Site is down" . Right now,  I don't see the print "Site is up" which gets written to my out.txt file.

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning `sys.stdout=f` which means all future prints to `stdout` will end up in `f`.  I'm really confused about why you're trying to make your local stdout go to a file, then trying to read from it--stdout is usually more of a "write only" stream for a program.

I think you might want to double check your logic, but once you do the assignment to sys.stdout that is where the output of all `print` statements will go.

Assuming the results aren't too huge and you have the memory for it you could do something like:

```
ssh.connect('xx.xxx.xxx.xx', username= 'xxxxxx', password= 'xxxxx', port=22)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('wget -O- http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7777 | grep "HTML"') #some application IP
f = open('out.txt', 'w+',100)
result = stdout.read()
f.write( result )
if 'HTML' in result:
    print "Site is up"
else:
    print "Site is down"
output = os.system ("type c:\python27\out.txt")
print output
f.close()
```

This will read the results into a variable, print that to a file and the search it for your HTML keyword.  You could also skip the `os.system` part by just printing `result` in my approach like

```
ssh.connect('xx.xxx.xxx.xx', username= 'xxxxxx', password= 'xxxxx', port=22)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('wget -O- http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7777 | grep "HTML"') #some application IP
f = open('out.txt', 'w+',100)
result = stdout.read()
f.write( result )
if 'HTML' in result:
    print "Site is up"
else:
    print "Site is down"
print result
```

and you can actually simplify this a bit more, since you're already using `grep` to see if HTML is in the result, you don't have to test it on your side, you can just see if anything at all was returned like:

```
ssh.connect('xx.xxx.xxx.xx', username= 'xxxxxx', password= 'xxxxx', port=22)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('wget -O- http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7777 | grep "HTML"') #some application IP
f = open('out.txt', 'w+',100)
result = stdout.read()
f.write( result )
if result:
    print "Site is up"
else:
    print "Site is down"
print result
```

If you really want your output file to contain a python list of strings of the lines you could do it like:

```
ssh.connect('xx.xxx.xxx.xx', username= 'xxxxxx', password= 'xxxxx', port=22)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('wget -O- http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7777 | grep "HTML"') #some application IP
f = open('out.txt', 'w+',100)
result = stdout.readlines()
f.write(str(result))
if result:
    print "Site is up"
else:
    print "Site is down"
print result
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But, if I print the stdout and try to use a IF/ELSE condition, then it doesn't give me correct result. 
CODE: 
for line in stdout.readlines(): 
print line.strip() stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('wget -O- xx.xx.xx.xx:7777 | grep "HTML"') 
print stdout.readlines() 
if 'HTML' in stdout.readlines(): 
print "Site is up" 
else: 
print "Site is down" ssh.close()
Output:
-------------------
['<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 ">\n']
Site is down
-------------------
Code is not able to make a decision based on stdout and it wrongly shows "Site is down".

Comment: note that I did not use `readlines` in mine, I used `read` to get the whole thing back as a string.  Unless you actually want/need a list of lines that contain `HTML` as a string you needn't get it as a list

Comment: @sama I have a version that should work for you with `readlines` too if you really wanted a python list written to the file

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. Both the suggestions worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You opened the file but didn't attempt to write to it, thus an empty file. This is a simple reproduction using urllib's HTTP request, but otherwise the file I/O part is the same:

```
import urllib.request

# return a http.Request object
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://google.com')                                                                           

# open the file for both reading and writing                                                                                                         
with open('out.txt', 'w+') as f:                                                                                       
    f.write(str(response.read())) 

    if 'HTML' in f.read():                                                                                                       
        print("Site is up")                                                                                                      
    else:                                                                                                                        
        print("Site is down")
```

As a plus, by using `with` context manager to open a file, you do not have to worry about closing the file afterward.